# Python 3 - Text file splitting by word, counting occurences and returning a list of sorted tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, optimization

I've already made a post about this but since then I managed to solve the issues I had at first since just editing the old question just makes things more complicated.

I have a text file with about 10'000 words. The output of the function should be: a list of tuples that have the word and the amount of occurences of that word as a tuple in descending order. For example:
out = [("word1",10),("word3",8),("word2",5)...]

So this is my code so far: (Keep in mind, this does work currently to a certain extent it is just extremely inefficient)

```
def text(inp):
    with open(inp,"r") as file:
        content = file.readlines()
        delimiters = ["\n"," ",",",".","?","!",":",";","-"]
        words = content
        spaces = ["","'",'']
        out = []
       
        for delimiter in delimiters:
            new_words = []
            
            for word in words:
                if word in spaces:
                    continue
                new_words += word.split(delimiter)
            words = new_words
  
        for word in words:
            x = (words.count(word),word)
            out.append(x)
            
    return out
```

I found some help from older posts on Stackoverflow for the first few lines.
The input should be the file path. This does work in my case. The first part (the lines I found on here) work nicely. Although there are elements in the list such as empty strings. My questions now are:

How can I sort the output such that the word with the most occurences comes first and then from that on in a descending order? Currently it is random. Also, I'm not sure if the same word comes up multiple times in this list. If yes, how can I make it such that it only occurs once in the output?

Also, How can I make this code more efficient? I used `time.time()` to check and it took almost 419 seconds, which obviously is terribly inefficient, since the task stated that it should take less than 30sec.

I apologize in advance for any mistakes I made and my lack of knowledge on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of running so many loops and conditions.
you can use [re.split](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/re.html)

```
import re
def text(inp):
    with open(inp,"r") as file:
        content = file.readlines()
        #delimiters = ["\n"," ",",",".","?","!",":",";","-"]
        words = content
        spaces = ["","'",'']
        out = []
        temp_list=[]
        for word in words:
            #using re.split
            temp_list.extend(re.split('[\n, .?!:;-]',word))
        for word in set(temp_list):
            x = (word,temp_list.count(word))
            out.append(x)
    return out
```

Comment: Okay I have to admit I never heard of re.split. What does it do exactly? Also, for sorting, would now ```sorted(out,key=lambda x: x[1] reverse = True)``` work for this case?

Comment: yes sorting will work `sorted(out,key=lambda x: x[1] ,reverse = True)`.
`re.split()` function takes two parameter `first: regex` and `second: string to split` and returns a list after splitting it based on regex used.

Comment: I see, Thank you! May I ask why you used ```print(temp_list)``` and then returned out. Is both necessary?

Comment: you don't need `print(temp_list)`. `temp_list` contains all the words in you file after the first for loop. second for loop will run for unique words in `temp_list`. and give you the count of each word in `out`

Comment: Thank you very much! There seems to be something strange happening. The word that occurs the most in the file seems to be ``` ' ' ```. I edited my code so now in the for loop, it checks if the word is in spaces. This does not seem to work. Where am I making my mistake?

Comment: add the space check in the second for loop

Comment: Thank you very much! That solved it. Apologies the many follow up questions